# How to move triangle over to the center right side of the screen in css?

Tags: html, css, button, center

This may be a silly question, but I have the following code in html:

```
  <h1 class="page-title">
  Paintings  
  </h1>
  <hr>
  </header>

  <div class="arrow1">
    <div class="triangle-right">  
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this in css:

```
.page-title {


 font-size: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid red;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

The triangle sits in the top corner of the screen, right below the header. I want to move it over to the right side of the screen and in the center. I also want to create another triangle on the left side and do the same.

My goal here is to create two triangle buttons. Can someone help me achieve this?

Comment: You want it on the right side and center?

Comment: I want it moved to the right side of the page, and then dropped to the center.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by having it center, like horizontally or vertically, but here is a solution that you might find helpful :)

```css
.page-title {


 font-size: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid red;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  float: right;
}

.triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid red;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
 float: left;
}

.arrow1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title">Paintings</h1>

<hr>

<div class="arrow1">
  <div class="triangle-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle-right"></div>
</div>
```

At the moment i've just set the `margin-top: 100px;` you can just adjust it so it fits what you want :)

Comment: Hey! I apologize for not being clear. The code works! I moved the margin down about 200 px to be at the center of the page. My only issue with this is that the left triangle is not at the left side.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaqsxsn3/)

Hope this one helps. M not sure what you want exactly.

```
display: inline-block;
```

use that display;